# What does it mean when a property is based on another

Tags: c#, properties

My problem is I am having problems setting a value to a property, that is "Based On" another property.

I am using a library that has these properties...

"**Completion:**
Gets or sets the completion rate value of the current task item (between 0 and 1), based on or updating the CompletedEffort property value accordingly."

"**CompletedEffort**:
Gets or sets the completed effort value of the current task item, based on or updating the CompletedFinish property value accordingly."

"**CompletedFinish**:
Gets or sets the finish date and time of the completion time interval of the current task item. This is a dependency property."

here is a list to the full link if that helps.. http://dlhsoft.com/GanttChartLightLibrary/Documentation/Reference/html/AllMembers_T_DlhSoft_Windows_Controls_GanttChartItem.htm

I am only trying to use the **Completion** Property so I have a line of code that looks like this.

```
                    Completion = projectTask.PercentComplete / 100;
```

PercentComplete is a double thats a property coming off the projectTask dataobject.

But this does not work. Completion stays 0.

Does that mean I need to change Completed finish, which will change completedEffort which will finally change completion?? Is that what all these "Based on or updating" means? 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**: Completion and PercentComplete are of type double. CompletedEffort is of type timespan and CompletedFinish is of type DateTime.

**EDIT 2**

```
 Completion = .8;
```

I set that as my code, and it still didn't change anything.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt you'll get a good answer here. "Based on or updating" is just the terminology the writers of that documentation chose to use, it doesn't *mean* anything inside of .NET to my knowledge. If you have access to the source, debugging it is likely the only way around your problem. Note that you could just be dealing with integer division here.

Comment: Sorry, edited the post, they are of type double.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in what is the value of `projectTask.PercentComplete` is that always 0?

Comment: No, it doesn't hit that line unless it has a value > 0.

@BradleyDotNET if thats the case then do you know why the value isn't even being set, even if I am just setting it like that?

Comment: From looking at those docs, it appears all three are simple auto-implemented properties with nothing fancy going on. Yet the fact that each one says "based on or updating" another property suggests that getting/setting one may affect the others. If you don't have access to the source code, you might consider installing a decompiler like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) so you can have a look under the hood.

Comment: You could try stepping into the setter (which could be problematic if you don't have source access). How do you know it is always 0? Do you look at it in the debugger after assigning it .8 and see that it is still 0?

Comment: Try setting the `Effort` property first. Looks like the properties are related.

Comment: Setting the finish would set the effort which would then do the Completion... very weird behavior especially they all have "sets" but yea.